# Kaplan Meier Curve is not showing ticks for censored data

Tags: python, survival-analysis

I am drawing a Kaplan Meier Curve in python. My KMC is fine but it does not show ticks for right-censored cases in my data. I tried a lot to show the ticks and here is the code that I wrote for this.  I don’t know why they are not appearing. I will be very thankful if someone could help to figure out the issue and the way to fix it. Here is my figure https://ibb.co/bPfFMxY

Many Thanks!

Python code:

```
def draw_KMC():
  # In actual code file, here are some code lines before drawing the KMC but for the sake of simplicity I am not adding those

  # ---- First Curve
  legend_label_1 = "Category A" 

  kmf_1 = KaplanMeierFitter()
  kmf_1.fit(durations = survival_times_A, event_observed=events_A, label=legend_label_A)


  # ---- Second Curve
  legend_label_2 = "Category B"
  kmf_2 = KaplanMeierFitter()
  kmf_2.fit(durations = survival_times_B, event_observed=events_B, label=legend_label_B)
  # ---- Third Curve
  legend_label_3 = "Category C"
  kmf_3 = KaplanMeierFitter()
  kmf_3.fit(durations = survival_times_C, event_observed=events_C, label=legend_label_C)

  ax = plt.subplot(111)
  plt.yticks(np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1), ['0', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70',  
  '80', '90', '100'])
  kmf_1.plot(ax=ax,  show_censors=True,ci_show=False,censor_styles={"marker": "|", "ms": 
  6} )

  kmf_2.plot(ax=ax, show_censors=True,ci_show=False,censor_styles={"marker": "|", "ms": 
  6})
  kmf_3.plot(ax=ax,show_censors=True,ci_show=False,censor_styles={"marker": "|", "ms": 6})

  plt.xlabel('Months since the completion date', fontsize=12)
  plt.ylabel('Proportion of studies w.r.t categories (%)')
  plt.grid(True)
  from lifelines.plotting import add_at_risk_counts
  add_at_risk_counts(kmf_1, kmf_2,kmf_3, ax=ax)
  plt.show()
```

**I even tried by replacing the *kmf.plt()* with *kmf.plot_survival_function ()* as well, but it did not make any difference and no ticks appear for censored data.**

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro your problem locally, but didn't see your observed behaviour. Can you try the following, simplified, code:

```py
survival_times_A = [10.9, 15.5, 20.3, 25.6, 30.8]
events_A = [True, False, False, True, True]
legend_label_A="test"


# In actual code file, here are some code lines before drawing the KMC but for the sake of simplicity I am not adding those

# ---- First Curve
legend_label_1 = "Category A" 

kmf_1 = KaplanMeierFitter()
kmf_1.fit(durations = survival_times_A, event_observed=events_A, label=legend_label_A)


ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1), ['0', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70',  
'80', '90', '100'])
kmf_1.plot(ax=ax,  show_censors=True,ci_show=False, censor_styles={"marker": "o", "ms": 
60} )

plt.xlabel('Months since the completion date', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Proportion of studies w.r.t categories (%)')
plt.grid(True)
from lifelines.plotting import add_at_risk_counts
add_at_risk_counts(kmf_1, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

What might be happening is that you have so many data points that the censored markings are getting "squeezed" out.

Also, can you tell us what version of `lifelines` you are using?

Comment: Also, I have a fix for that annoying misalignment of `Category C` in your at-risk label: https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifelines/pull/1278#issuecomment-849191193

Comment: Thank you very much @Cam.Davidson.Pilon for your response. I have tried the simplified code but still I cannot see any ticks for censored data. My CSV file contains several thousand censored data values. The lifeline version is 0.26.0. How can I show the ticks to represent the censored data?

Comment: that's so strange... can you confirm your version of matplotlib for us?  Can you post a screenshot of the plot from the simplified code?

Comment: matplotlib version is 3.4.2.  I can see the dots in your simplified version (earlier I said I cannot, I was doing something wrong then, apologies for that). Here is the plot from the simplified version. https://ibb.co/Y3y2Sq3

Comment: So your code and setup are fine. I suspect it's some rendering issue in matplotlib. In your original code, try something crazy like `censor_styles={"marker": "o", "ms": 15}`

Comment: Keep in mind too, that you may be display thousands of censored ticks - possible creating a lot of noise - is that going to be useful for your analysis?

Comment: I tried different things but nothing helped me out in displaying the ticks. 1) I played with the style and size of the markers (kept trying different sizes). 2) I tried the same code on smaller datasets (even on just ten records too). 3) I tried to draw KMC in SPSS with this large dataset and there I can see the ticks, but my requirement is not SPSS. I want to draw it in Python. For your second comment: Yes, that is fine in my analysis. It's annoying, that I cannot see the ticks. Any help to fix it will be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the data with me? I don't know what's doing on... email is in my github profile